# Firing shouldOverrideUrlLoading()

Tags: android, webview

I have some logic I want my WebView to apply whenever I try to change its url. For links within loaded pages it's fine, I can just do it by using shouldOverrideUrlLoading method on my custom WebViewClient.

But when I explicitly call loadUrl on my WebView, shouldOverrideUrlLoading is not fired (obviously, or it would produce an endless loop when calling loadUrl from within this method).

Is there a way to "preload" a url manually so the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method is called?

```
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        if(url.startsWith("myapp://")
        {
                //Do something
        }
        else {
                view.loadUrl(url);
        }
        return true;
        }
```

This works fine when I click a link from within the rendered page. But if I call:

```
mWebView.loadUrl("myapp://whatever");
```

`shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` is not called. What I am asking is whether there's a way that I can pass a url to my webView so it gets passed through to `shouldOVerrideUrlLoading()` before actually loading it. (i.e. `shouldOVerrideUrlLoading()` is called whenever  a new url **is about** to be loaded. That's the event I want to fire)

REF: [Android's official WebView documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: what you need 1st webview.loadurl(URL); or shouldOverrideLoading ?

Comment: I would like to take advantage of my shouldOverrideUrlLoading logic whenever I manually need to change my webview's url, whithout having to replicate code.

Comment: post your code snippet for better understanding

Comment: I tried to clarify it a little bit but really there's no code I can post for what I am asking.

Comment: @Gabriel have you found an elegant solution to this? Right now I am holding a reference to the client and calling if `(!client.shouldOverrideUrlLoading()) { view.loadUrl(url); }` instead of just `view.loadUrl(url)`

Answer (score 0):

if your app version greater then 'N' you should use this function

```
shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)
```

check you function and version

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to do is re-use your logic, just extract it into your WebViewClient and use that to load the url and then just delegate to this in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`():

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    return loadUrl(view, url);
}

public boolean loadUrl(WebView view, String url) {
    if(url.startsWith("myapp://")
    {
        //Do something
    }
    else {
       view.loadUrl(url);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then instead of

```
mWebView.loadUrl("myapp://whatever");
```

You do:

```
mWebViewClient.loadUrl(mWebView, "myapp://whatever");
```